# MySQL inner join among three tables syntax

Tags: mysql

My tables:

```
mysql> select * from pvf_order;
+------+------------+------+
| oid  | orderdate  | cid  |
+------+------------+------+
| 1001 | 2014-02-10 |    1 |

10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from pvf_order_item;
+------+-----+----------+
| oid  | pid | quantity |
+------+-----+----------+
| 1001 |   1 |        2 |

18 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from pvf_product;
+-----+----------------------+----------------+--------+--------------+
| pid | prod_desc            | Prod_finish    | price  | prod_line_id |
+-----+----------------------+----------------+--------+--------------+
|   1 | End Table            | Cherry         | 175.00 |            1 |

8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Right now my query has been variations of:

```
SELECT 
pvf_order.cid, 
pvf_order.orderdate, 
pvf_product.prod_desc, 
pvf_order_item.quantity, 
pvf_product.price 
FROM pvf_order 
INNER JOIN pvf_order.oid=pvf_order_item.oid
INNER JOIN pvf_order_item.pid=pvf_product.pid
WHERE YEAR(pvf_order.orderdate)=2014 AND MONTH(pvf_order.orderdate)=10;
```

I just don't know exactly where I'm going wrong. I edited some of the info out just to avoid a big wall of text, but I hope the general idea is there. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to have these changes : `INNER JOIN pvf_order_item ON pvf_order.oid=pvf_order_item.oid` AND `INNER JOIN pvf_product ON pvf_order_item.pid=pvf_product.pid`

Comment: It should be `INNER JOIN pvf_order_item ON pvf_order.oid=pvf_order_item.oid
INNER JOIN pvf_product ON pvf_order_item.pid=pvf_product.pid` You need to mention which table to join, not just which fields to match.

Answer (score 0):

Check **[JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)** sintaxis, also use **[ALIAS](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)** for table names

```
SELECT 
    o.cid, 
    o.orderdate, 
    p.prod_desc, 
    oi.quantity, 
    p.price 
FROM pvf_order o
INNER JOIN pvf_order_item oi
        ON o.oid = oi.oid
INNER JOIN pvf_product p
        ON pvf_o.pid = p.pid
WHERE YEAR(o.orderdate) = 2014 AND MONTH(o.orderdate) = 10;
```

Also instead of use Year and Month function, you can simplify to one single comparasion operation.

```
WHERE date_format(o.orderdate, '%Y-%m') = '2014-10'
```